# Elevation on a layout which has a shape drawable background with different corner radii

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-drawable

I have a layout for the list item which looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_very_small"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_large"
    android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_very_small">


    <LinearLayout
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@drawable/red_bubble"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_small"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="TEST"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="yesterday"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the background for the LinearLayout is a shape with red color and rounded edges:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@color/red"/>

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

Question is, why does elevation work, and there is a shadow, when all edges have same radii, but when I change radius for one of the angles (bottom left in this case) shadow disappears?

[image: Test]

And is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Try specifying your shape as rectangle like rather than not specifying and see if it works  like this in your shape `<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >`

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Why dont you use Card View and forget this tiresome elevation set in Linear Layout because I am sure CardView always works

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get it back by setting a ViewOutlineProvider and passing in the same shape via a path.